# Cannot get Oracalize to work on Ropsten

Tags: oracles

I have tried to run Oracalize as 1:1 of the example provided on their site. During the creation of the contract, I am also sending 1 ether to it (so it is not empty). Still even 30 minutes after this, there appears to be no callback to the contract.

Contract address: 0xbedb1be6c46ac0bc708bc93e3b17edc7751b1187

There are 0 incoming transactions: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4e3ffaca2ea2a0afd838116493adcb6d714f5963

Comment: Did you create an Oraclize query in your constructor?

Comment: Yes, I used the example from their site as 1:1 (there they run the query in the constructor).

Comment: Ropsten is forked, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44296/ropsten-network-down and https://twitter.com/BokkyPooBah/status/979664768901394434

Answer (score 0):

From [Oraclize gitter](https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api?at=5a6dfe7540259f1a33ba3ade) as of 28th Jan 2018:

> ...experiencing some issues on ropsten recently, if you could try on a
>   different test network this might help...

Had the same issue on Ropsten. Kovan worked fine.

Comment: All testnets should be fully operational now.