# Ropsten Network down?

Tags: nodes, ropsten, network

According to Etherscan the last mined block was block 2933931.

However, my node is stuck at block 2933993.

On their [website](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) they are announcing the following: "Node Resynch in progress. Indexing will restart once the synch has been completed."

Does anybody has any idea what is going on with Ropsten?

Comment: Found this on twitter: https://twitter.com/BokkyPooBah/status/979664768901394434, you might want to try to connect to the right node. A fork has happened and etherscan appears to be on the wrong fork.

Comment: @MathematicalRain Thanks. I have tried connecting to the node that the tweeter is suggesting. It brought me straight to block 2934047. Now it is stuck syncing on that block.

Comment: What version of geth/parity are you using?

Comment: v1.9.5-unstable

Comment: Duplicate of my question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43827/whats-going-on-at-this-address-is-ropsten-testnet-being-attacked-again

Comment: did you get your node to resync?

Comment: @de_ninja No, I have migrated to Kovan.

Comment: Finally got my node to resync... I retried so many times.. might work for you now

Comment: @de_ninja Good to hear. https://ropsten.etherscan.io is also working again. Will try to resync tomorrow.